# Unable to read Local language data from an Excel using csv

Tags: python, django, csv, python-3.8

I am giving data as "यह एक नमूना संदेश है" in a CSV file. I am reading the data inside the file using CSV Module in python.
sample code:

```
  csvFile = request.FILES.get('file')
  csv_copy = copy.deepcopy(csvFile)
  file_content = csv_copy.read()
  decoded_file = file_content.decode('utf-8').splitlines()
  reader = csv.reader(decoded_file)
  rows = list(reader)
  for i,row in enumerate(rows):
      print(row[1])
```

the given data is getting converted as "???? ???? ???"
Is there any way to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Try using different encoding format eg. **`utf-16`** or  you can check more formats [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codec-base-classes)

Comment: Give an example of the actual file lines and makes sure the file is actually encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: It's just as likely that the data is being read correctly but you're unable to output it.  Which OS/version and Python version are you using?

Comment: Also why are you using `copy.deepcopy` on the file object? If you want to read that file multiple times you can just run `csvFile.seek(0)` after reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Saving CSV file with CSV UTF-8(.csv) format worked. Thanks for the response.